# JavascriptMVC and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, javascriptmvc

I am trying to setup a project to use javascriptmvc and twitter bootstrap.  I used the app generator built into javascript mvc to create the file structure, and then added a resources directory.

```
-AppRoot
    -documentjs
    -funcunit
    -jquery
    -appname
        -fixtures
        -models
        -resources
            -css
            -js
            -img
      .
      .
      .
     -appname.html
     -appname.js
```

I have configured my appname.js so that it reads:

```
steal(
    './appname.css',            // application CSS file
    './models/models.js',       // steals all your models
    './fixtures/fixtures.js'    // sets up fixtures for your models
).then(
    './resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
function () {                   // configure your application

    }
)
```

It doesn't appear as though any of the bootstrap files are being included. Any ideas / suggestions on the proper way of setting up javascriptmvc and bootstrap would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file structure you mentioned above you do not have a bootstrap folder, you have css, img and js directly in the root of resources so you should include your files without that folder:

```
steal(
'./appname.css',            // application CSS file
'./models/models.js',       // steals all your models
'./fixtures/fixtures.js'    // sets up fixtures for your models
).then(
    './resources/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './resources/js/bootstrap.min.js',
function () {                   // configure your application

    }
)
```

Or move css, img and js into bootstrap folder so your includes work.